# Overflow error in Python with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfTABU8VeoY&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfHt4XU7vTm22xDegR0v0fQ&index=7 for data analysis with pandas but when I want to run following code

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas.io.data   
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

sp500 = pd.io.data.get_data_yahoo('%5EGSPC', start = datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 15),
                                  end = datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 15))
sp500.to_csv('sp500.csv')

df = pd.read_csv('sp500.csv', index_col = 'Date', parse_dates=True)

df['H-L'] = df['High'] - df.Low
df['100MA'] = pd.rolling_mean(df['Close'], 100)
df['Difference'] = df['Close'].diff()

threedee = plt.figure().gca(projection='3d')
threedee.scatter(df.index, df['H-L'], df['Close'])
threedee.set_xlabel('Index')
threedee.set_zlabel('Close')
threedee.set_ylabel('H-L')

plt.show()
```

It produces both in Jupyter notebook and PyCharm an error as follows:

```
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)    
C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
        305                 pass
        306             else:
    --> 307                 return printer(obj)
        308             # Finally look for special method names
        309             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in <lambda>(fig)
    225 
    226     if 'png' in formats:
--> 227         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
    228     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
    229         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
    117 
    118     bytes_io = BytesIO()
--> 119     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    120     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    121     if fmt == 'svg':
```

with many others various paths including matplotlib.py and as on.
What's wrong? It isn't too much data to load, is it?

Comment: Please show the complete traceback, and indicate which line in your script is causing the `OverflowError`. It would also be useful to know which version of Pandas you're using: `pandas.io.data` isn't supported in the current version.

Comment: I appended more of Traceback to the question. I'm using the same version of pandas as in the tutorial from Anaconda 2.7, to run things more smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried replacing this line

```
threedee.scatter(df.index, df['H-L'], df['Close'])
```

with the following?

```
threedee.scatter(range(len(df.index)), df['H-L'], df['Close'])
```

You are plotting timestamps as values. It is possible that `matplotlib` doesn't understand what numerical values the timestamps carry.

Edit: unfortunately, this workaround this workaround turns the xaxis ticks into a numberic range. But we can always set the ticks manually:

```
threedee.scatter(df.index, df['H-L'], df['Close'])

renderer = fig.canvas.get_renderer()
threedee.draw(renderer)
old_xticks = [t.get_text() for t in threedee.xaxis.get_ticklabels()]
new_xticks = [df.index[int(t)].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
               if t is not '' else '' for t in old_xticks]
threedee.xaxis.set_ticklabels(new_xticks)

threedee.set_xlabel('Index')
threedee.set_zlabel('Close')
threedee.set_ylabel('H-L')

plt.show()
```

Comment: I replaced the line you've given me and it works! But why?

Comment: @StanislavJirák the overflow was caused because every element of that `df.index` was a `Timestamp`. If you take a look on its value representation, you'll see that, e.g., `df.index[0].value` is `1444867200000000000`! That's probably why `matplotlib` went nuts.

Comment: I see now. Thanks again!